# Como realizar um select com 2,7 bilhões de registros em toda tabela?

Tags: hive

Ao fazer um determinado *select* em uma tabela com cerca de 2,7 bilhões de registros o *Hive* retorna erro. Mas incluindo um `LIMIT 2147483647`, o *select* não da erro.

O problema é que eu preciso varrer **toda a tabela** e não apenas 2.147.483.647 registros. Haveria uma maneira de resolver este problema?

Comment: É realmente necessário varrer toda a tabela? Se precisa fazer isso, tente definir `offsets` e percorrê-los com um delay.

Comment: Sim. Offsets não são reconhecidos na versão do software que trabalho. Mais alguma sugestão?